# Max Value search in array using fork and pipe

Tags: c, arrays, pipe, fork

I have to write a c program (linux) to search max value in an array, useing 10 child in the same time. The array size is 1000. Each child searching the max from 100 numbers. The parent should get the results on pipelines. My code doesnt work perfectly. The main problem is the pipelines. The parent get only the first max. The second problem is that the childs arent running in the same times (not a huge problem but probably someone can told me what is wrong)
I make some notes for my code, but my english is so bad sry.
I hope i copy the source code in right form.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>



int main()
{
int array[1000];       //main array
int i;
srand (time(NULL));     //for not the same numbers
for(i=0;i<1000;i++){    //array upload
array[i]= ( rand() % (10000+1) );    //from 1 to 10000 random numbers
}
int searchminindex;   //search index, 0-100,100-200, etc
int searchmaxindex;
int threads = 10;    //number of threads
int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
int arraymax[10];    //the 10 max numbers
for(i=0;i<threads;i++){             //for 10 threads
if(fork() == 0){
    close(fd[0]);               //close reading
    searchminindex=i*100;           //number of thread * arraysize/threadsnumber
    searchmaxindex=(i+1)*100;
    int maxindex=searchminindex;            //it will store the max number index, start from the search min index
    int j;
    for(j=searchminindex;j<searchmaxindex;j++){ //max search
        if(array[maxindex]<array[j]){
            maxindex=j;
        }
    }
    write(fd[1], &array[maxindex], sizeof(array[maxindex])); //write the max number into the pipe
    printf("max: %d\n", array[maxindex]);   //that for check the result, will be deleted from the final code
    close(fd[1]);               //close write
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
}
else{
wait(NULL);
close(fd[1]);               //close write
read(fd[0], &arraymax[i], sizeof(arraymax[i])); //read the max and store in arraymax[]
close(fd[0]);                   //close read
printf("the read max from the pipe: %d\n", arraymax[i]);  //that for check the result, will be deleted from the final code
}
}

int arraymaxi=0;        //it is search the max in the main array for check the result, will be deleted
int k;
for(k=0;k<1000;k++){
if(array[arraymaxi]<array[k]){
    arraymaxi=k;
}
}
printf("maxi: %d\n", array[arraymaxi]);    //end of checking the correct result, will be deleted
int l;                  //check the max numbers from the forks, will be deleted
for(l=0;l<10;l++){
printf("from the pipe max: %d\n", arraymax[l]);
}
int h;                  //search the true max from the 10 numbers
int truemaxindex=0;
for(h=0;h<10;h++){
if(arraymax[truemaxindex]<arraymax[h]){
    truemaxindex=h;
}
}
printf("the final max: %d\n", arraymax[truemaxindex]);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After each time you call `fork`, you wait for the process you just created to finish. You should create all your processes before you wait for any of them.

You have a few other bugs. You close `fd[1]` in each pass of the loop, but then try to read from it in the next pass of the loop. You can use a different pipe to each child if you want, but if you're going to use the same pipe to all the children, you need to leave the pipe open until you've read all the responses.

Also, don't call `exit` in the children! This can cause very surprising behavior when the parent's `atexit` handlers run more than once. You can use `_exit`.

Comment: Thanks! I delet all close and wait, now it works perfectly! All child run in the same times and the parent get all result. But then where sould i close the read and write? After the first for? or not necessary to close?

Comment: @AsdFork You should close a pipe end when no needed. If you think about it *both* ends must remain open for the duration of your fork-loop, as each child needs to get the write-side, and the parent will eventually need the read-side. Btw, a simple adaptation of your code that also solves your concurrency problem [can be seen here](http://pastebin.com/zUnUPGPN). Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the for loop in the parent, you close the read side of the pipe on the first iteration, so the read in the second iteration is failing.  Move the close outside of the loop.  (And check for errors!!)